# Счет в диапазоне по двум условиям

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

1й столбец - список с повторяющимися значениями (текст).

2й столбец - значения (цифры).

3й столбец - желаемые значения.

Возможно ли формулой сделать подсчет кол-ва ячеек не равных 0 из второго столбца для каждого значения из первого столбца?

Есть суммесли, но будет просуммированы значения, а нужно просто кол-во.
https://yadi.sk/i/7ksyS2FjrER75A

```
ААА 0   1
ААА 4   1
ААА 0   1
БББ 0   0
БББ 0   0
ССС 0   3
ССС 1   3
ССС 3   3
ССС 0   3
ССС 1   3
```

Comment: не понимаю как в них сделать, чтобы счет происходил в другом столбце. В суммесли выбирается диапазон, выбирается критерий из этого же диапазона и выбирается диапазон откуда брать значения для суммирования.

Comment: ссылку на ядиск добавил, не знаю как тут сделать чтобы пригодно было для копипаста в эксель.

Comment: Ctrl-C в Excel, Ctrl-V тут, выделить вставленное, нажать кнопку `{}` (которая "пример кода"). И всё.

Comment: чето у меня при таком способе в эксель копируется в одну ячейку всю строку)

Comment: У меня то, что сейчас выше - нормально копируется в Excel, и вполне пригодно для "текст по столбцам".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Cx=СЧЁТЕСЛИМН($A$y:$A$z;Ax;$B$y:$B$z;"<>0")
```

где:

- x - текущая строка
- у, z - начальная и конечная строки таблицы данных

В принципе, если сверху-снизу ничего нет, можно и просто

```
Cx=СЧЁТЕСЛИМН($A:$A;Ax;$B:$B;"<>0")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вроде как работает, попробую к себе прикрутить. Видимо я не правильно понял СЧЁТЕСЛИМН, думал только в одном диапазоне считает, а критериев много.

Comment: @skawn Ну не зря же оно СЧЁТЕСЛИ**МН**. Потому что `СЧЕТ ЕСЛИ МН`ого условий.

Comment: условий то да, а вот диапазонов много я не предполагал) Спасибо.

Comment: @Akina, задавать весь столбец не советую. Это со `СЧЕТЕСЛИ` нормально прокатывает - она умеет определять пользовательский диапазон и ниже его считать не будет. `СЧЁТЕСЛИМН` не такая и будет перелопачивать весь столбец

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант

```
=СУММПРОИЗВ(--($A$2:$A$99=A2);--($B$2:$B$99<>0))
```

Иногда спасает, но для данной задачи лучше применить `СЧЕТЕСЛИМН`